# How can i generate PAT (personal access token) from tableau dynamically

Tags: single-sign-on, tableau-api

I am working on a project where i am implementing sso using jumpcloud and tableau and while accessing data from tableau, PAT token should pass which i am passing from my account. But how can i make it dynamically after sso login for every user.

Any suggestions would be helpful

tried documentation and article from internet but unable to find any solution on this

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem supported officially:

> Users must create their own PATs. Administrators cannot create PATs for users.
>
> Note: A user can have up to 10 PATs.

See the *Create personal access tokens* section on the [Personal Access Tokens](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/security_personal_access_tokens.htm) official documentation page.

It may be worth looking into [user impersonation](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_auth.htm#impersonating_a_user) but I do not think this is a sound solution.

Comment: Sounds like a sound plan, here guest to my house, go make your own copy of the keys to the front door, make up to 10 if you like, help yourself.

Comment: @easleyfixed I don't write the docs, I just reference them.

Comment: Oh trust me, I am not shooting the messenger, sounds like you agree perhaps?